# Spelling Error in Data Explorer FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, spelling

[Data Explorer FAQ](http://odata.stackexchange.com/faq)

> Why are my queries not showing up **int** the recent query list?

Surely "int" should be "in"?

Comment: No, this is SO type coercion at work.

Answer (score 1):

Also,

> Do you support parameterized **quries**?

should be **queries**

Comment: arrrrhhrhrhrhr fixing a single typo takes upwards of 30 minutes on Azure, I am done fixing the first one, now we will have to wait another half hour for this